# image button which can be clicked outside of FORM

Tags: php, html

I want to simply put an image button inside my PHP without using any forms.

I did it with simply doing :

```
<input type="image" src="/images/buttons/button.gif"/>
```

So is there any way I can add any function to it ? I only want to redirect the page to another page by clicking the image button.

If there is any other way too, please let me know.

( I'm new to PHP and started learning about a month ago )

Thanks.

Comment: If you are going the `<input>` route vs what the answers suggest, please update it to `<input type="image" src="..." alt="Put a description here" />` so if people who have disabilities access it, they know what it does

Comment: @Rayan B, thanks so much. it is a great tip, and be sure i'll use it this way in future. Thanks again. ( I deeply wanted to vote for your answer, but i guess i can not :(

Comment: you should be able to since your rep is over 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to redirect to another page, then use the image as a link:

```
<a href="another_page.php"><img src="/images/buttons/button.gif"/></a>
```

Comment: No problem. This is actually a plain HTML issue, instead of PHP. You may want to check into HTML specs and information ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/ ) to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a hyperlink:

```
<a href="pageToGoTo.php"><img src="/images/buttons/button.gif" /></a>
```

Comment: (Two same answers) But Thanks for your answer. ;)

Comment: ya. But for me it sticks longer in my mind, because two php coders, suggest the same function in a matter of seconds. Thanks again. ( BTW it makes it hard for me to vote from you both )